# Finding specific value in list using threading

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have a large text data from my list, and my problem is too slow finding specific values. Because I have to find 50+ keywords from the list.

here my is working script:

```
for num, line in enumerate(MyList):
    passList = []
    if "pass" in line:
      passList.append(line)          

    failedList = []
    if "failed" in line:
      failedlist.append(line)

    doneList = []
    if "done" in line:
      doneList.append(line)

    #.. 
    #...
    #....more and more conditions here
```

Is there any way to have a fast execution or using thread if there is no other solution.

Any suggestion/comments, thanks in advance..

Comment: Why don't you parse the line and check if the word you are looking for is in the exact position? Please show the format of the line as well.

Comment: Can you use grep?  It is certainly faster.

Comment: @thefourtheye, yup I am finding that exact value and right now I am just use that dummy string to find but in actual in my if condition it is also in the list.

Comment: @ fiacre Im sorry but im just a beginner for this im not yet familiar with that grep.

Comment: Sorry. Without seeing the format of the lines suggesting optimizations is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing a complete scan of every line once for each keyword.  You want to find your match in a single scan.  Regex will do this much more efficiently.  Simply construct a regex pattern that includes all of your keys and match against it:

```
keys = ('foo', 'bar', 'stat', 'key', 'abcd', 'efgh', '$')
pattern = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(keys))

data = [
    'this is foo',
    'this is bar',
    'this is abcd',
    'this is efgh',
    'this is no match'
]

results = defaultdict(list)
for string in data:
    match = pattern.search(string)
    results[match.group(1)].append(string)

print results
```

Comment: I got your point here, but now I am trying to analyze if it will be fast when I find 50+ specific keywords from the list.

Comment: and?  I'd be curious to see the results.  I suspect you will get an improvement. The magnitude of the improvement, though, will depend on the nature of your data and your keys.